# Insert derived sum value of a column into another table as a record in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, insert, derived-table

I got error on oracle database

> ORA-00936: missing expression

I dont know how to properly insert a record on a table which is a sum of all the value from another table.

```
    INSERT INTO initial_transaction_inventory
    VALUES (10000, SELECT SUM (pyi_total_price) FROM payable_inventory, SELECT SUM (pai_total_cost) FROM paid_inventory, SYSDATE, utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('C:\Users\username\Documents'));
```

This is what i'm trying to do with my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the brackets as follows:

```
INSERT INTO initial_transaction_inventory
VALUES (10000,
        (SELECT SUM (pyi_total_price) FROM payable_inventory),
        (SELECT SUM (pai_total_cost) FROM paid_inventory),
        SYSDATE,
        utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('C:\Users\username\Documents'));
```